# Display notification when unattended-upgrades is running

Tags: xfce, unattended-upgrades, xfce4-power-manager

I configured unattended-upgrades on xubuntu (20.04) desktops. I manage my own apt repository, so I can still manage what package to update and when. While unattended-upgrades is running, the reboot/shutdown buttons from xfce power menu are disabled. Unfortunately, users think this is bugged and force shutdown by pulling the plug and make their system unbootable...

I wonder if there is a way to display a notification while unattended-upgrades is running to make sure the user doesn't force shutdown their computer. Or better, make the unattended-upgrades a little more robust.

Comment: What about the "minimal-steps" option in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades?

Comment: Already enabled. Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent the system to become unbootable if the user pull the plug while an upgrade is currently being installed.

Comment: Hmmm. I think you have perhaps discovered a bug: If minimal-steps in enabled, then I expect shutdown buttons to not be disabled. Consider reporting it so the developers can discuss: `ubuntu-bug unattended-upgrades`